# Invalid GeoJSON object

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am trying to draw a json coordinates in leaflet map.Here is my data

```
var location={
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"coordinates": [80.2066734649931, 13.0187039189613]},
      "properties": {
          "assetStatus": "FULL",
          "id": 1747,
          "item": "53 Trailer"
      }
    },
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"coordinates": [ 80.2072495864164, 13.0191043036246]},
      "properties": {
          "assetStatus": "EMPTY",
          "id": 1746,
          "item": "53 Trailer"
      }
    },
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": { "coordinates": [ 80.2067574402883, 13.0191983952581]},
      "properties": {
          "assetStatus": "LOADED",
          "id": 1745,
          "item": "53 Trailer"
      }
    }
  ]
}


L.geoJson(location, {
            style : fillAssetColorStyle
        }).addTo(map);
```

Am getting `Invalid GeoJSON object.` error.Is my data structure correct? Anyone help me guys please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are missing to put geometry type. `"type": "Point"`

GeoJSON supports the following geometry types:

**Point**, **LineString**, **Polygon**, **MultiPoint**, **MultiLineString**, and **MultiPolygon**.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [80.2066734649931, 13.0187039189613]},
      "properties": {
          "assetStatus": "FULL",
          "id": 1747,
          "item": "53 Trailer"
      }
    },
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [ 80.2072495864164, 13.0191043036246]},
      "properties": {
          "assetStatus": "EMPTY",
          "id": 1746,
          "item": "53 Trailer"
      }
    },
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": { "type": "Point","coordinates": [ 80.2067574402883, 13.0191983952581]},
      "properties": {
          "assetStatus": "LOADED",
          "id": 1745,
          "item": "53 Trailer"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Would be extremely useful to also point to the GeoJSON spec and possibly some linting tools.

Comment: when I add `type:Polygon` am getting `Invalid GeoJSON object` error.

Comment: Check required coordinate for polygon

Comment: yea checked ji..am getting `Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)` after changing the structure

Comment: `"coordinates": [[
            [-109.05, 41.00],
            [-102.06, 40.99],
            [-102.03, 36.99],
            [-109.04, 36.99],
            [-109.05, 41.00]
        ]]`   check this format or visit http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/